# Converted PDF from Word document and wrong title is being displayed

Tags: pdf, cpu-word

I used a Microsoft Word template to make a few documents, and I then converted those documents into PDFs by Saving as PDF. I'm displaying the PDFs in a web page but all the PDFs have the same title on the web page. I cannot find anywhere where there is a "title" for a Word document and I'm nearly at my wits end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I was looking at Word instead of the PDF itself. I can change the title funder File > Properties in Adobe Acrobat Pro DC.